# How can I implement the modulus operator in Commodore 64 Basic?

Tags: commodore-64, basic

How can I implement the modulus operator in Commodore 64 Basic?
There are not a lot of math functions to work with, and modulus would be very handy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using this expression

```
A-INT(A/B)*B
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For a power-of-two modulus in the range 2 to 32768, nothing will beat using the `AND` operator with a value of (modulus-1).  While the version of Microsoft BASIC on the Apple won't allow such usage, the one in 8-bit Commodore machines will.  One could compute "Y=X mod 32" via `Y = X AND 31`.  While this approach only works for powers of two, it is definitely worth using for scenarios involving such values.

Answer (score 4):

While I'd be inclined to put it into a DEF FN() statement, the problem is that functions only take one argument and for modulo you need two.

As others noted, you can write a subroutine for this - easy enough. However, if you want to be a bit more clever and you're not using the USR() function for anything else, you could follow the code listed on [this page which described how to implement a USR() call](https://www.softwolves.pp.se/cbm/artiklar/usr.en.html) to machine language code on a C64 and they've specifically implemented MOD with it.

Answer (score 0):

The following implements Y % X, populating RE with the remainder.

Below I set up 103 % 10 on lines 10 and 20 as an example use.

```
10 x = 10
20 y = 103
30 gosub 1000
40 print re
50 end
1000 rem mod operation
1010 re = y - ((y/x)*x)
1020 return
```

Comment: Slow algorithm. But more importantly shouldn't 1010 reference RE instead of R?

Comment: RE = Y - ((Y/X)*X); would be a way to get the modulo with no iterations.

Comment: It would need to be Y-(INT(Y/X)*X) but that's about as good as you'll get with the built-in BASIC. There are several extensions such as Simon's BASIC that add explicit modulo functions though.